# Copy of SD in second Pi - system work but several services do not start

Tags: hardware, sd-card

I have 2 Raspberry Pi 2B
On 1st I run Openhab, mysql, Mosquitto and Apache2
This is my home automation server.

Now I want to make copy of system and use it on 2nd Pi to test some changes.
I copy SD card by win32diskimager, shutdown original Pi and power 2nd Pi which boot correctly. I can login with same user as on original Pi but mosquitto is not running, can't connect to HTTP, can't connect to mysql.
IP address is same as original Pi.
Any clue what can cause such issues please?

Answer (score 1):

Your os (orc router, but I don't think so) may have strict checking enabled. 
In osx (your host system may differ), 
you need to delete the raspberry pi related line in
/Users/##usrname##/.ssh/known_hosts
Because it knows the difference. You have to do this every time you switch cards if you have a static IP setup, wether assigned at the router or in /etc..
Then you can ssh into your pi after it boots, assuming you have it configured to auto connect to your network on boot. 
Plus update with results. 
O150N

Comment: Hi and sorry for late answer,  I just checked and deleted known_hosts file on my RPI nevertheless this did not fix my issue - I can SSH to this RPI even before this file deletion. Is there any simple method how to see what is causing system to behave different on new hardware please? (when I use same card with copy in original RPI  system works correctly. Both RPI are same hardware B+